# Error in communicating LabView Client VI with WinCC OPC Server over the network (LAN)

Tags: networking, labview, plc, opc

I'm trying to automate some system using Siemens PLC; for that we have developed a WinCC Flexible RT application for control and monitoring, and have also declared the PC based HMI panel as the OPC server. Which is working fine.

Now, when i try to create a OPC Client application either in WinCC or Labview, on the same PC, am able to access all the tags of the server on the client, am able to do so.

When i try to create the client application on some other computer connected over the local area network [perfectly fine and well configured network working], am unable to access the OPC server/tags in that case.

What can be done in this case.?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to establish connection between OPC client and server applications is to perform the following:

1. turn off the firewalls on both machines
2. create the same windows account on both machines using the same login name and password
3. for windows account (pointed out in 2) allow all "access permissions" and "Launch and Activation Permissions" by running "dcomcnfg" command and navigating to "console root->component services->computers->my computer->com security"

The more detailed example of how to do steps described above is given in this article http://opc-da.com/Winsetup.html

Also, there is a powerful OPC client API implemented on LabVIEW using OPC .NET API with detailed documentation on how to use: http://opc-da.com

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you mentioned the OS on the server and the client computers. Anyway, I'm guessing that this is a DCOM issue, as @Ken mentioned.

It's been a while since I worked with this sort of thing, but you can try this article: http://www.opcactivex.com/Support/Tutorials/DCOM_Tutorial_-_Configuring_th/DCOM_XP/dcom_xp.html and see if it helps.

Comment: Ive tried to configure the DCOM as shown in tutorial. But its not working. I tried on the Both Machines but all in vain. The OPC is not visible in the client.

Comment: Which OSs are on the machines? Do you have identical users (with identical passwords) on the server and the client?

Comment: Hey... I tried some DCOM Settings ... the OPC server is visible on the Client Machine. But when i select the OPC Server following errors are returned :
**LabView** :: IOPCBrowseServerAddressSpace [Error]
**WinCC Flexible** :: COM Server doesnot support the interface **OpcRcw.Da.IOPCServer** could be incorrectly installed proxy ... DCOM security setting ... apersonal firewall activated ....


I have deactivated the firewalls on both the systems [One is XP-Sp3 other is Win 7]

Comment: Please Help in this regard

Comment: Did you follow every step from the documentation on setting up DCOM correctly? 
Also, it could be a bit easier if you use exactly the same username and password on the machines.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the firewall isn't blocking the connection. Disable it on both sides.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this NI article:  http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvhowto/psp_firewall/

keep in mind, the tcp ports used by OPC/shared variables changed somewhere between LV2009 and LV2011, so depending on what version you have, the ports may be different.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the ports and the firewall...
Make sure that the account in which the the OPC client is running has access to the OPC server, either through the DCOM default settings or the OPC Server-specific settings (also part of DCOM configuration) on the server machine.